# How to set up celery persistent state database

Tags: python, django, celery

Celery task revocation is stored in the memory, so it will not persist when worker is restarted. 
In Celery documentation it can be persisted using command `celery -A proj worker -l info --statedb=/var/run/celery/worker.state`

http://celery.readthedocs.io/en/latest/userguide/workers.html#worker-persistent-revokes

but when I run the command, I got error file not found, so I created the file, I ran the command again but then it tells me db type could not be determined.

I try to lookup how to set the persistent database to use in celery but got no results. Any help will be apreciated

Comment: Glancing at the source, celery.worker.state looks like it's using shelve to persist things.  A shelf database should be created by the open call if it doesn't already exist.  What was the exact error that you received before you tried creating the file yourself?

Comment: it shows: celery _gdbm.error: [Errno 2] no such file or directory.
When I create the directory `/var/run/celery` and run the command again it show permission denied. Therefore I run the command using sudo privilege, it didn't show any error but there's a warning running with sudo is not recommended.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it turns out, I have to create the directory first and celery worker should be permitted creating a file in that directory.

My solution was to create `celery` directory in the project then run command:

`celery -A proj worker -l info --statedb=celery/working.state`
and it works